# Measurable function constant on uncountable set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. We have given the Sigma-algebra $\Sigma$, the collection of subsets  $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ where either $A$ or $A^{c}$ is countable or finite.

I want to show that f is measurable if and only if there exists a contable set $A$ such that for $x \in A^{c}$ $f(x)=const$

I found a similar question for one direction here:

[Measurable function remaining constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5827/measurable-function-remaining-constant)

But the answer given is unsatisfactory for me since I don't see why $f^{-1}([n,n+1])$ needs to be either countable or co-countable, since [n,n+1] is not necessary in $\Sigma$.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is $\Sigma$-Borel measurable or $\Sigma$-$\Sigma$ measurable?

Comment: It is supposed to be $\Sigma-\Sigma$ measurable but I start to question whether holds in this case.

Comment: The identity is $\Sigma$-$\Sigma$ measurable, and it's not constant on the complement of any countable set.

Comment: Alright so my promise is wrong , thanks, now the answer in the linked question is clear of course.

Comment: Please write an answer yourself, since this question seems to have been answered.

Comment: So we are trying to prove $f$ is $\Sigma$ to $\mathcal B$ measurable iff the "constant" condition holds? Here $\mathcal B$  means the Borel sets.